# Knockout Template Binding not tracking elements within the observable array

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I want to create a dynamic table with knockout where I can add elements to an observableArray. My code goes to the point that I can create the elements, but I cannot Remove them, as well as the elements that are created within the template are not "observing" correctly, by that i mean not at all.

Here is my code:

```
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a id="ATS" href="#Add"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Duration</td>
                        <td>Qty Employees</td>
                        <td>Requires Labor</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: Jobsteps">
                    <tr data-bind="template: 'AddStep'">
                        <%--template goes here--%>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the Viewmodel:

```
var MyDataViewModel = {
        Jobsteps: ko.observableArray()
        }
  $('#ATS').on('click', function () {
            MyDataViewModel.Jobsteps.push({ StepName: "", Duration: "", QTYEmployees: "", RequiresLabor: true });
        });
    $('#RTS').on('click', function () {
        MyDataViewModel.Jobsteps.remove(this);
    });
```

The Template

```
    <td><a href="#Add"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: StepName" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Duration" class="input-mini" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: QTYEmployees" class="input-mini" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: RequiresLabor" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a id="RTS" href="#Rem"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></a>
    </td>
```

Comment: `MyDataViewModel.Jobsteps.remove(this);` "this" refers to element that triggers the event, not the item to delete.

Comment: Ah, good to know ty :) stil a KO n00b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, firstly you are creating with that template multiple items that has the ID RTS so i believe that jquery will get confused.

Secondly I also believe that the jquery bidings wont take effect as the items your are trying to bind to does not exist yet.

Here is what I suggest:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: MyDataViewModel.AddClick"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Duration</td>
                    <td>Qty Employees</td>
                    <td>Requires Labor</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Jobsteps">
                <td><a href="#Add"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></td> <!-- no idea what this is for btw -->
                <td>
                     <input type="text" data-bind="value: StepName" /></td>
                <td>
                     <input type="text" data-bind="value: Duration" class="input-mini" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: QTYEmployees" class="input-mini" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: RequiresLabor" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: MyDataViewModel.EditClick"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And then your knockout

```
var MyDataViewModel = {
    Jobsteps: ko.observableArray(),
    AddClick: function(){
        MyDataViewModel.Jobsteps.push( ko.utils.unwrapObservable( ko.mapping.fromJS( { StepName: "", Duration: "", QTYEmployees: "", RequiresLabor: true })));
    },
    EditClick: function(item){
        MyDataViewModel.Jobsteps.remove(item);
    }
}
```

Feel free to when you implement this to move your table's body back into a template, also remember to never call ko.applyBindings more than once on an element set